# ECSlidingViewController and UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, subview

I'm trying to use https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController and cloned with its demo app, which starts with 3 ViewControllers.

I have successfully implemented a table view in the FirstTopViewController (which is the default view when you launch the app), except that I can't have didSelectRowAtIndexPathMethod open a sub view with details about the touched cell.

I looked around and found an example app at http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/10/ios-5-storyboard-and.html on how to do exactly what I was trying to do (which is implement a table view inside a standard view), but I can't find a reason why it doesn't work.

Could there be anything special to do due to the way ECSliding works ? The code I use when a row is select is

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    UIViewController *rowDetail = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RowDetail"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rowDetail animated:YES];
}
```

**EDIT:** self.navigationController is (null), so I now know why it doesn't work, haven't found yet how to make it work

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UINavigationController should work the same as any other UIViewController.

Make sure that you are setting the topViewController to the UINavigationController instance, not to one of its child view controllers.

Comment: The thing is, I don't have a UINavigationController. I just started from the example app and added a table inside the FirstTopView.

Comment: After some more reading I planned to start from scratch to try something new and did a fresh clone. Doing a test build before anything, I discovered that you had just updated your example app. You rock!